# If you are a GRA are you consider fully funded?

Tags: funding, cv

I have nearly completed my Master of Science. Refreshing my Resume. I have been funded as a GRA every semester I was a Master's student – meaning my tuition was waived and I received a month stipend.

Is it the correct terminology to state:

> "Was fully funded as a Graduate Research Assistant (GRA) for _________ Institute of
> Technology while pursuing his Master of Science."

Is that correct, or is the term "funded" more-so used for PhD students or those that secure guaranteed funding for X number of years. In my case, I essentially kept renewing my GRA positions on a semesterly bases.

Last, should I explicitly mention that my tuition was waived and I received a month stipend, or do employers not care about that.

Comment: It sounds to me like you were fully funded, but I do not see why this would be mentioned in your CV.  CVs for industry jobs are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** I'm not aware of the term "funded" having a strict or legal definition. If you got paid every semester, then it sounds like you were fully-funded, and it's fine to say this.

As for what employers want, I'm sure this varies widely, but I doubt that being "fully funded" by itself will count for much. If you had to go through a competitive, merit-based process to "win" funding, it might be worth a bullet explaining this achievement.